# Symbolizing 3d polyline by z-value using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, symbology, line, 3d

I have a polyline with z-values.  I need to symbolize the polyline by z-value.  There doesn't appear to be any way to do this.

How can I do this using ArcMap 10.2?

A color ramp symbology is the sort of thing I'm looking for. The individual line segments are too long of effectively symbolize by some summary statistic like Zmin/max/avg/etc. I need the symbology to be continuous or nearly so.

Comment: What result are you expecting?  Can you please [edit] your question to give a bit more detail about what you're trying to do and how you want it to look?  Have you looked at ArcScene?

Comment: Use add Z information tool to add statistics of your choice to lines table

Comment: A color ramp symbology is the sort of thing I'm looking for.  The individual line segments are too long of effectively symbolize by some summary statistic like Zmin/max/avg etc.  I need the symbology to be continuous or nearly so.

Comment: @Alpheus So you're wanting each single line to vary in color as the `Z` changes?

Comment: Split line at vertices if you've got advanced licence

Answer (score 1):

[@FelixIP's comment](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/230406/arcgis-10-2-symbolize-3d-polyline-by-z-value#comment357697_230406) worked for me at 10.7.1.  I ran the *Add Z Information* tool and it added the Z values to the shapefile's attribute table.  From there I could symbolize my layer.